# Ceph iSCSI Gateway installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ansible, iscsi, ceph

I'm installing Ceph using Ansible with ceph-ansible project, branch static-3.2. There is a problem with iSCSI Gateway installation.

If you are using iscsigws name in inventory file - it shows that This is available only for RHEL. (Still doesn't work Out of the Box on Centos7, since missing yum packages, but maybe this works better in newer branch of ceph-ansible). What is needed to make it work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm installing Ceph using Ansible with ceph-ansible project, branch static-3.2.
There is a problem with iSCSI Gateway installation.

If you are using iscsigws name in inventory file - it shows that This is available only for RHEL.  (Still doesn't work Out of the Box on Centos7, since missing yum packages, but maybe this works better in newer branch of ceph-ansible)
I need to install this on Ubuntu, that is not so easy

At this point I've installed this manually. Maybe it will be usefull not only for me.

You need to have proper configuration files. You Can define name [iscsi-gws] and copy group_vars/iscsigws.yml to group_vars/iscsi-gws.yml

It will not install propely - but It will handle proper configuration for you. So it's still very usefull

Also you can just skip to manual installation, but there You need to remember that you will need /etc/ceph from other machines in stack copied, and iscsi-gws.cfg file created, even the simplest one from this manual:

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/iscsi-target-cli/

I know there's manual at http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/iscsi-target-cli-manual-install/

But it doesn't work correctly, since tcmu-runner is only RHEL friendly.

Have a nice time :)

In Manual thay say, U need 4.16 kernel at least so that's why I'm updating - Maybe it's unneccessary

```
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-headers-4.19.0-041900_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_all.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-headers-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-modules-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
dpkg -i *.deb

apt-get install git mc cmake make gcc kmod libkmod-dev libglib2.0-dev libnl-genl-3-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev librbd-dev librbd1 librados-dev librados2 python-pip python-rpm
git clone https://github.com/open-iscsi/tcmu-runner
cd tcmu-runner/
cmake -Dwith-glfs=false -Dwith-qcow=false -DSUPPORT_SYSTEMD=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make install
cd ..
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable tcmu-runner
systemctl start tcmu-runner
git clone https://github.com/open-iscsi/rtslib-fb.git
cd rtslib-fb/
python setup.py install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/open-iscsi/configshell-fb.git
cd configshell-fb/
python setup.py install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/open-iscsi/targetcli-fb.git
cd targetcli-fb/
python setup.py install
mkdir /etc/target
mkdir /var/target
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/ceph/ceph-iscsi.git
cd ceph-iscsi/
python setup.py install --install-scripts=/usr/bin
cp usr/lib/systemd/system/rbd-target-gw.service /lib/systemd/system
cp usr/lib/systemd/system/rbd-target-api.service /lib/systemd/system
pip install netifaces
pip install flask
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable rbd-target-gw
systemctl start rbd-target-gw
systemctl enable rbd-target-api
systemctl start rbd-target-api
cd ..
```